# Error building openssl-sys crate on Windows

Tags: windows, openssl, rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to compile a Rust program on Windows, but I get this error message:

```
Compiling openssl-sys v0.6.4
failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.6.4`

[...]

failed to execute command: The system couldn't find the specified file. (os error 2)
Is `gcc` not installed? (see https://github.com/alexcrichton/gcc-rs#windows-notes for help)

--- stderr
thread '<main>' panicked at 'explicit panic', C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-0a35038f75765ae4\gcc-0.3.12\src\lib.rs:510
```

Cargo compiled every other package without problem, but it can't compile the openssl package.

I searched for help with this specific error and found a [github issue for hyperium](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/607). The first answer references the [openssl building guide for Windows](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl#windows).

I don't understand exactly how I have to build openssl in Windows. I installed MinGW and added the bin path to the global `PATH` variable, so gcc is reachable, but this did not solve the error.

I use Rust 1.2 and Cargo 0.4.0. [My project](https://github.com/LukasKalbertodt/telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/simple.rs) is an example for a Telegram API wrapper.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can run `gcc` in the same shell that you are running `cargo` in, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download ssl

> Installs Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2d

Install it here: C:\OpenSSL-Win32，C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include,C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib

2) Install MinGW,and add system env path ,,C:\MinGW\bin,important,MinGW's installed path contain char 'MinGW '

3) `cmd run env OPENSSLLIBDIR=C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib OPENSSLINCLUDEDIR=C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include cargo build`